# Ubuntu 17.10 xrdp

Tags: server, lubuntu, 17.10, remote-desktop

I spend most of my life on Windows Machines, but I have spent a little time on Linux systems. Forgive me if I seem naive at all.

I have recently got a VPS and put Ubuntu 17.10 on it. I installed Lubuntu Core (GUI) on it as I'd like to ease into the command line as slowly as possible.

My next step is to RDP onto it from my Windows 10 laptop. This seems easy enough from the tutorials that I have read through. I install xrdp the same way as [this site](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=11336) says to but I get one issue.

When I am told to edit the `Xwrapper.config` file, I go to look for it, but it doesn't exist.

I have tried to RDP to the site still, and it lets me log in, but once I have logged in, it sits on a blue window. I am assuming that this is because I haven't made the edits in `Xwrapper.config`.

Why would this file not be getting installed for me? How can I go about RDPing to this server?

This is what I see once I try and RDP onto the server.
[image: RPD Window Popup]

Comment: Ubuntu Core doesn't have anything but command line or cmd in Windows terms. There is no desktop environment to RDP to.

Comment: @mikewhatever I seem to have managed to install one. I followed some steps laid out by Vultr.com for adding a GUI to Ubuntu. It has allowed me to use the desktop through the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read first this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq#What.27s_the_difference_between_desktop_and_server.3F
In Ubuntu server there is no "desktop" in windows terms installed by default. If you insist to use RDP or VNC to log into the desktop, then better install the desktop version of the Ubuntu, which is easier than installing the "desktop" environment on Ubuntu server, and is already pre-configured. When you use the VPS as a server, then better option for administration is the ssh aka command line interface. It has more powerful options as using the RDP only. There is possibility to manage the VPS via browser interface (e.g. yunohost, openmediavault), but it cannot compare to command line (ssh) where you can run arbitrary command on your VPS.

Generally speaking, if you want to use desktop environment on your server, then this will consume resources, but it will not bring so much benefit.

Comment: Assuming that I am ok with the the extra resources being consumed, and I have installed a GUI interface already, how would I go about using xrdp on it when the Xwrapper.config file does not exist for me?

Comment: If you know the path, create it.

Comment: @Buck I did this, but I don't know what to populate it with. I just added the line that i needed, rebooted the system, and I was still unable to RDP.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the guide you are following assumes that you are using the default Gnome desktop. You are using Lubuntu GUI on a server and it doesn't work for you.

Check your home directory, if you have `.xsession` file. If not, create it. You should have this entry in the file `lxsession -e LXDE -s Lubuntu`.

Restart the xrdp service:

```
systemctl restart xrdp
```

I tested on a fresh server installation and it worked for me. It should work for you too.